# How to "design\think database format"

Tags: c#, mysql

i have an order number like xx12345 that contains a quantity of 200.
The order is divided like xx12345A and xx12345B each A and b contains quanity of 100.

I will make a program that loads in database  the ORDER (xx12345) and the quanity  (200) from barcodescanner.

How to check if xx12345A with quanity 100 and xx12345B with quanity 100 belongs to xx12345 with total sum of 200 qty?

I don`t know how to create the database and connect xx12345 A and B to orderxx12345 . I`m using C# and Mysql

Comment: how can `xx12345A` "belong" to `xx12345B` if they have different order numbers?

Comment: @Plutonix, the "parent" order is xx1234 with qty 200, and iti is divided in two little orders xx1234A with qty 100, and xx1234B with qty 100.